# Prevent Option+R from turning into ®

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I would like to use <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> as a shortcut in Obsidian, but every time I hit it, I get the registered trademark symbol: ®.

How do you turn this shortcut off? I looked in *System Preferences -> Keyboard* and couldn't find it.

Comment: Opt-R -> ® is not a shortcut, it's the default keybinding (basically all Opt combinations produce a character). Does binding functionality to an Opt combo work for other keys in Obsidian?

Comment: To elaborate on what nohillside wrote, option+R becoming ® is similar to how Shift+4 becomes $. Option is not sufficient to create a keyboard command, it's a modifier key only.

Comment: On a Mac you need to use control or command for menu shortcuts, since option is used for special characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-generating-special-characters-when-pressing-the-alta-optiona